# Cordova compile error

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova

I have a cordova project and has two platforms, android and ios. I build the ios project in the root folder by issuing the following command.

cordova build ios

But i get the following error.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Does anyone know what might be the reason behind this?
I am new to cordova and any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if this solves the issue :)

Answer (score 10):

Try running `cordova platform update ios` - this seems to be a known bug.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/220

Comment: That was hard to find! Had this when checking out the repository on another machine, couldn't find a difference between them.